# How to rename, or even access a column with spaces in its name?

Tags: sql, databricks

A table with one of the column names as 'Person Rank' is uploaded on Azure, and then accessed via Databricks Notebook.

So writing sql statements using this column is giving errors, even renaming it is a problem.

All the following commands give errors:

```
SELECT Person Rank FROM Table1
SELECT 'Person Rank' FROM Table1
SELECT "Person Rank" FROM Table1
```

How to access this column in sql command?

Comment: What errors did you get exactly in each case?

Comment: ideally you should be using `person_rank` as SQL naming convension, also improves RDMS portablity

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes but it was an already uploaded table on Azure, which can't be modified; just accessed via databricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Databricks uses the backtick to escape identifiers, so try:

```
SELECT `Person Rank` FROM Table1
```